# Ber. 43 (33). Yosef seats the brothers in birth order. This could have revealed his identity prematurely?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yosef, miketz

In [Beraishis 43 (33)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.43.32?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), Rashi quotes the Medrash to say, Yosef

> “struck the goblet and called aloud: Reuben, Simeon, Levi, Judah,
> Issachar and Zebulon, sons of one mother, take your seats at the table
> in this order which is the order in which you were born — and
> similarly in the case of them all. When he reached Benjamin’s name he
> said, “This one has no mother and I have no mother — let him sit
> beside me”.

The brothers were astonished at this behaviour. Yosef was not yet ready to reveal himself to his brothers. Why then did he perform this 'trick'? Was he not worried that his identity might be revealed through it?

Comment: He performed the trick in order to "show" them the "power" of the goblet, in order to give them a motive to steal it. All that so he could put the goblet in the bag of Benjamin. And he did this to test them if they would risk their lives for one brother, to revert their sin of selling him

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The whole point is that they could not conceive of the idea that this was Yosef. They thought that he was capable of the magic powers of Egypt. Thus, when he framed them for stealing the *magic cup* they would seem to have a motive.

Also they at most would think that he had purchased Yosef as his slave and gotten the information from him. They might have thought that Yosef had risen to the post of a trusted slave of the vizier, not the vizier himself. This would keep them there trying to find Yosef.

Comment: Yeah it seems they were so blinded by their assumptions that he figured he could get away with it. Seems obvious to us, but from where they stood, "magic cup" made more sense than "the guy we sold as a slave is now in power."

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the comment which I accept. Can you now please answer "Why did he perform this 'trick'?"

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok He did this in order to set up the thought that he had the magic powers of Egypt. He also allowed them to think of the possibility that he had purchased Yosef as a slave and had gotten the information from him. That way they would not try to get away before he was ready.